# LLM Hallucinations on In-Context Data

Tags: large-language-models, prompt, benchmarks

I know of some benchmarks that LLMs do undergo, but I am no expert whatsoever. I think what I am wondering about is closest to [TruthfulQA](https://paperswithcode.com/dataset/truthfulqa).
The question came up when I heard of combining company data with LLMs by providing the internal, sensitive data in prompts à la [RAG](https://research.ibm.com/blog/retrieval-augmented-generation-RAG) (of course you do not want to fine-tune the model every time, because the data may change daily or even hourly, but instead supply it with the data in prompts).

So the question is:
How sure can one be about the correctness of the models outputs on these kinds of prompts? I do not want it to hallucinate here whatsoever; that would undermine the whole approach of using LLMs in this context. Are there benchmarks *specifically* made for this task (i.e., providing lots of information in context and then asking for things appearing in this context)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How sure can one be about the correctness of the models outputs on these kinds of prompts? I do not want it to hallucinate here whatsoever; that would undermine the whole approach of using LLMs in this context?

No way to be 100% sure, e.g. see [Large Language Models Cannot Self-Correct Reasoning Yet](https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.01798). There can be some tricks to reduce or detect some hallucinations though.

> Are there benchmarks specifically made for this task (i.e., providing lots of information in context and then asking for things appearing in this context)?

Yes, e.g. [PDFTriage: Question Answering over Long, Structured Documents](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2309.08872.pdf) but we are waiting for the permission to release data+code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, great input!